# NestedScrollView scroll down itself when content is fills

Tags: android, nestedscrollview

I have xml, which consits of `DrawerLayout`, `CoordinatorLayout` with `custom views`, `AppBarLayout`, `NestedScrollView`.

**Problem:** When content in `NestedtScrollView` fills, `NestedtScrollView` scrolls down itself. 
All researches like `scrollView.setScrollY(0)` or custom class for `layout_behavior = FixedScrollingViewBehavior` didn't help me.

How do i prevent this scrolling

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:background="@color/semitransparet_color_primary">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/actionbar_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:elevation="4dp"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/product_scroll_wrpr"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="gone">

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                // my content is here

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>



    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttons_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="#01579B"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

    // here are my buttons

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header_left"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu"/>
```

my **build.gradle** consits

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Try to set `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the `LinearLayout` inside `NestedScrollView`. It works for me.

**UPD:** beware of using into the layout descendant elements like `EditText`, which should take a focus: that elements will not take a focus. If you know how to solve this, please let us to know.

Comment: It worked, but what is the explanation for this one?

Comment: Does it mean that focus on the views inside will be blocked, and users won't be able to reach them?

Comment: Maybe you could explain this a little bit further, this would improve your answer quality.

Comment: If you have any `TextView` elements with `android:textIsSelectable="true"` this will block text selection. Better to just set the parent view to focusable.

Comment: If I can put a thousands of upvotes I would do it. Was struggling for two days trying to understand why it happens or at least make a workaround. It was also a lot of data binding around so totally looked like a black magic before I found this solution.

Answer (score 19):

An alternative to blocking the focus, is to add a new View that will steal the focus. Put it anywhere above the NestedScrollView, and it should work:

```
    <!--focusStealer, to avoid NestedScrollingView to scroll due to dynamically created views that take the focus-->
    <View
        android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="0px" android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
```

Comment: This works fine if your NestedScrollView contains EditText views!

Answer (score 6):

This working for me:

```
mNestedScrollViewChat.post(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        mNestedScrollViewChat.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in Kotlin

```
 nestedScrollView.post { nestedScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN) }
```

Answer (score 0):

add `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"` and  add  and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`android:focusableInTouchMode="true"' in children view of Nested ScrollView
becase nestedScrollView need focus a view before scroll. i try focus a Edittext from children of view to get focus

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtAddressAccount"
        style="@style/StyleEditText"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:nextFocusUp="@+id/edtAddressAccount"
        android:nextFocusLeft="@id/edtAddressAccount"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/edtDistrict"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView13"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13" />
```

full code here

```
 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/nestedAccount"
android:layout_weight="1"
tools:context="jp.co.ramen.ui.auth.account.AccountFragment">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"

    >

    <jp.co.ramen.utils.customview.DropDown
        android:id="@+id/spGenderAccount"
        style="@style/StyleSpinner"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/edtAddressAccount"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView14"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView14" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        layout="@layout/include_text_require"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/edtAddressAccount"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtAddressAccount" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtDistrict"
        style="@style/StyleEditText"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:nextFocusUp="@+id/edtAddressAccount"
        android:nextFocusLeft="@id/edtAddressAccount"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/liner2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView12"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView12" />
...more view
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```