# Nested scrollview automatically scrolls to bottom

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a GridView within a NestedScrollView. I have used the code below to resize the GridView whenever the content of the GridView is changed. This works fine, however the NestedScrollView scrolls to the very bottom when I swipe from fragment 3 of the app back to fragment 2 (where the NestedScrollView resides). This doesn't happen when swiping from fragment 1 to fragment 2, oddly. It also doesn't happen directly after resizing the GridView.

How can I repress the NestedScrollView from scrolling to the bottom?

```
private static void resizeGridView(GridView gridView, int items, int columns) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = gridView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = singleGridHeight * items;
    gridView.setLayoutParams(params);
    gridView.requestLayout();
}
```

The following system methods are called when swiping between fragments:
[image]

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/36261638/1621111

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the child layout in NestedScrollView

Comment: EditText's after this not focusable

Comment: Worked like a charm !!!, just added one thing is, after adding the above solution, EditText will not get focused then on EditText touch listener just add yourChildView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS); . Your EditText will get focus.

Answer (score 1):

If I add `nestedScrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);` to the end of the `onLayoutChanged()` method of the GridView the issue is resolved. However, it would make more sense to prevent the nestedScrollView from automatically scrolling in the first place.

Ideas?