# CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsed with nested scrollview by default

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I don't understand why my *CollapsingToolbar* layout is collapsed when my view is created by default.

I think this the `NestedScrollView` the responsible but i don't no why.

This make me crazy.

My activity layout :

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager_images"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_product" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And my content_layout with nested scrollview :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <include layout="@layout/layout_progress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_reference"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/MyApp_gray"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view_choix"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="1dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_quantity_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="@string/product_quantity"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <com.MyApp.utils.HorizontalNumberPicker
                android:id="@+id/horizontal_qty_picker"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1px"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:background="@color/MyApp_gray" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_price"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_price_unit"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text=" / Unité"
                    android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_duration"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_hourglass_red_18dp"
                android:drawablePadding="4dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/MyApp_gray"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_book"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_primary"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_add_shopping_cart_white_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="@string/store_action_book"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_desc_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@string/product_description"
        android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="1dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">

            <at.blogc.android.views.ExpandableTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="5"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/MyApp_gray"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:animation_duration="1000" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_more"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="@string/action_expand"
                android:textColor="@color/MyApp_red" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Rendering :
[image: Rendering]

More strange it still working when i use the *NestedScrollView* to top. It seems like the *NestedScrollView* scroll to bottom automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this thread :
[nestedscrollview-scroll-down-itself-when-content-is-fills](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34419859/nestedscrollview-scroll-down-itself-when-content-is-fills)

`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the `LinearLayout` inside `NestedScrollView`

Worked for me.