# How to prevent a recyclerview from getting automatically scrolled to the last item's position when items are added to it?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I understand that we can use the methods notifyDataSetChanged() to add new elements to the recyclerview and update the view, but I need the transition to be smooth.

When I tried using a Transition with a LinearInterpolator, I could achieve the effect, but the scroll automatically jumps to the last position of the updated list  and I need to avoid that.

```
moreButtonClicked(){
                viewMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                rcAdapter.moreClicked = true;
                rcAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Transition changeBounds = new ChangeBounds();
                changeBounds.setDuration(3000);
                changeBounds.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator() );
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(myCityList,changeBounds);
}
```

This code makes it autoscroll to the last item of the recyclerview. The other thing about this problem is that it happens only sometimes. I need to mention that my recyclerview is within a  Nestedscrollview

Answer (score 0):

I just figured the solution, I just needed to put `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on the layout inside the NestedScrollView which helped me get rid of this issue.

Thanks to this post which helped me get rid of this issue
[NestedScrollView scroll down itself when content is fills](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34419859/nestedscrollview-scroll-down-itself-when-content-is-fills)